# Recursively create Object from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, recursion

I need to create an object from a JSON file.
The Input Json file looks like this.

```
{  
   "test":{
      "Record":1,
      "RecordValues":{  
         "Address":"3330 Bay Rd.",
         "City":"Los Angeles",
         "SecondObject":{  
            "1":"eins",
            "2":"zwei"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

What i have so far is this function..

```
var test = [];
function recFunc(obj, parent_id = null) {

    for(var i in obj) {
        if(typeof obj[i] == "object" && obj[i] !== null) {
            test.push({title: i, children: []});
            recFunc(obj[i], (test.length-1));
        }else {
            if(parent_id != null) {
                test[parent_id].children.push({title: (i + " : " + obj[i])});
            }else {
                test.push({title: (i + " : " + obj[i])});
            }
        }
    }
    return test;
}
```

The output object should be as follows.

```
[  
   { "title":"Record : 1" },
   {  
      "title":"RecordValues",
      "children":[  
         { "title":"Address : 3330 Bay Rd." },
         { "title":"City : Los Angeles" },
         {  
            "title":"SecondObject",
            "children":[  
               { "title":"1 : eins" },
               { "title":"2 : zwei" }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: That target object looks like a very bad design. Can you explain why you need that?

Comment: @trincot the target object is needed for javascript plugin fancytree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.entries` and `reduce` with recursion

```js
let obj = {"test":{"Record":1,"RecordValues":{"Address":"3330 Bay Rd.","City":"Los Angeles","SecondObject":{"1":"eins","2":"zwei"}}}}

let recursive = (obj) =>
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((op,[key,value]) => {
  let final = typeof value === 'object' ? {title:key, children:recursive(value)} 
                                        : {title: `${key}: ${value}`}
  return op.concat(final)
},[])


console.log(recursive(obj.test))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible approach, recursively iterating over the `Object.entries`:

```js
const input = {
  "test": {
    "Record": 1,
    "RecordValues": {
      "Address": "3330 Bay Rd.",
      "City": "Los Angeles",
      "SecondObject": {
        "1": "eins",
        "2": "zwei"
      }
    }
  }
};

const makeNested = (currInput) => {
  return Object.entries(currInput).map(([key, val]) => (
      typeof val !== 'object'
      ? { title: `${key} : ${val}` }
      : {
          title: key,
          children: makeNested(val)
        }
  ))
};
console.log(makeNested(input.test));
```

Comment: I will try that when i come home. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and recursively call the function if the nested value is an object:

(The `Object(value) === value` checks if the `value` is an object which is not `null`)

```js
const obj = {test:{Record:1,RecordValues:{Address:"3330 Bay Rd.",City:"Los Angeles",SecondObject:{1:"eins",2:"zwei"}}}};

function transform(obj) {
  return Object.entries(obj).map(([key, value]) => {
    if(Object(value) === value)
      return { title: key, children: transform(value) }
     else
      return { title: `${key} ${value}` }
  })
}

console.log(transform(obj.test))
```

Comment: You reached here faster +1

Comment: and i was messing around using reduce :p i need to practice more about recursion for sure :)